# Bind the Ctrl + <number> keys to firefox in Ubuntu

Tags: firefox, cinnamon, shortcut-keys

In Firefox on Windows, I can cycle through tabs using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1–9</kbd> etc. However Ubuntu (with Cinnamon) seems to not allow this binding. How can I restore it?

Comment: how about Ctrl+tab to loop through tabs ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Ubuntu <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Number</kbd> doesn't work. Instead you have to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Number</kbd>

Both Alt keys work. This works on Chrome and Firefox and File Manager... essentially anything with tabs open.

It works in Unity, GNOME and Cinnamon (as you wanted).

> How am I supposed to close tabs
>   -–  HackToHell

You can close tabs with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. This also works on windows and Mac (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>)

> I suppose there is no way to restore it back to good old Ctrl+ ? –  HackToHell

Alt + Number is just as easy as Ctrl + Number (just a matter of getting used to it). I think that Ctrl + Number may be used for other ubuntu things?

The amount you would gain from rebinding it is nowhere near the effort you would put in to change a system wide shortcut key.

Comment: How am I supposed to close tabs ? Alt+F4 closes firefox. Ctrl+f4 used to close the tab.

Comment: Ctrl + W, same as windows.

Comment: I suppose there is no way to restore it back to good old Ctrl+<number> ?

Comment: Alt + Number is just as easy tbh... I think that Ctrl + Number may be used for other ubuntu things...? The amount you would gain from rebinding it is nowhere near the effort you would put in to change a system wide shortcut key.

Comment: I use Alt+Number for my i3, and have for many months. Wish I could change it...

Comment: how is this the accepted answer for saying it 'does not work'?

Comment: @user because it does not work and can not be changed.

Comment: we can put a sports car into space, and you are telling me the default shortcuts in an open-source software running on an open-source OS can not be changed

Comment: @user well you could download the source code, edit the necessary parts, then compile and install it.

Comment: if you had found which parts to edit, that would have been an acceptable answer to this question

Comment: @user you think I’ve got the time to hunt through the Ubuntu source code and find the places to edit, then provide instructions to how to make those edits, and how to compile and install it, and keep this answer updated for every new version? Haha. If this answer is unhelpful please downvote it. If you know a way to do it, please post a new answer. Otherwise, this conversation is rather redundant.

Comment: I also like to use ctrl in firefox because in "i3 window manage" the alt+number shortcut switches workplaces, BUT apperently "alt" is hardcoded and can't be changed via, say, about:config. Here someone wrote a plugin:
https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/6w9wub/how_to_use_ctrl19_to_switch_tabs_instead_of_alt19/dm6nj6c/  -- the associated bugreport: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1389644 -- the link to the webextension: https://gist.github.com/zbraniecki/000268ea27154bbccaad190dd479d226

Answer (score 7):

The Firefox Add-on *[Addressable-Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/addressable-tabs/)* let's you do exactly what you requested. Basically sets the hot-key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1–9</kbd> while also maintaining the <kbd>Alt</kbd> shortcuts. Works with Ubuntu 18.04 on Firefox Quantum.